# UITableViewCell custom class - Reload cell height after change in subview height constraint

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a button in custom `UITableViewCell` class. It shows/hides a view (part of same cell). The height of cell should change on doing that.
This is the button action (in `UITableViewCell` custom class):

```
@IBAction func showHideCartView(sender: UIButton)
    {
        if sender.tag == 1
        {
            // Show cart view
            self.buttonArrow.tag = 2
            self.viewAddToCart.isHidden = false
            self.constraint_Height_viewAddToCart.constant = 50
            self.buttonArrow.setImage(UIImage(named: "arrowUp.png"), for: .normal)
        }
        else
        {
            // Hide cart view
            self.buttonArrow.tag = 1
            self.viewAddToCart.isHidden = true
            self.constraint_Height_viewAddToCart.constant = 0
            self.buttonArrow.setImage(UIImage(named: "arrowDown.png"), for: .normal)
        }

        self.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()
        self.setNeedsLayout()
        self.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
```

The height of cell remains unchanged. It is only when I scroll the UITableView and revisit the cell, it's height gets updated.

Comment: I have implemented something very similar to yours but all I had to do was "        self.tableView.beginUpdates()
        self.tableView.endUpdates()". Please give that a try

Comment: @Siyavash : I have written the above in UITableViewCell custom class

Comment: oh thats probably why then , I will write a possible solution

Comment: @Siyavash : It would be quite easy to do that from UITableViewCell class as well. But I am afraid if that is the right way to do that.

Comment: but the reason "The height of cell remains unchanged" until you "scroll the UITableView and revisit the cell" is probably because your tableview is still using the old cell

Comment: Instead of using one cell, you can use 2 cells and put the condition when where you have to show cart cell.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add the following method to the `viewController` with the `tableView` to refresh the table when a cell is expanded:

```
func refreshTableAfterCellExpansion() {
    self.tableView.beginUpdates()
    self.tableView.setNeedsDisplay()
    self.tableView.endUpdates()
}
```

Call the method after the constraints have been updated. If the button manipulates the constraints inside the cell, you will need to notify the `viewController` about the change so that you can call the method. Either use a delegate pattern (or pass directly a `tableView` reference to each expandable cell - just remember to store it as `weak` variable), or post a notification using `NotificationCenter.default`.

Answer (score 1):

As this code is in the TableViewCell, You need to make a action method for your cell in the TableViewController so when the button is clicked you would know. You can keep a reference of your button in your tableviewCell and then inside the cell cellForRowAt you can do

```
cell.yourButtonRef.addTarget(self, action: #selector(expandButtonTapped(_:)), for: .touchDown)
```

and the make a function called "expandButtonTapped" and add the tableview beign and end update there

```
@objc func expandButtonTapped(_ button: UIButton) {
    self.tableView.beginUpdates() 
    self.tableView.endUpdates()


}
```

Please let me know if this has worked or not