# Programmatically creating an expanding UItableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a tableviewcell that I want to expand and collapse on tap. All the examples I have found are Storyboard base and I am trying to do this programmatically. What I thought initially was to create a subview and constrain it to the content view but when I adjust the height of the cell with `heightForRowAt` it also increases the size of the content view (which makes sense). Any thoughts on how I should go about this?

For visual reference here is what I want to happen[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use vertical `UIStackView` with the bottom view `isHidden` set to true, then on tap (or whatever is the trigger of the expand) just change the `isHidden = false`. I guess that would be the easiest, considering how `UIStackView` deals with `isHidden`. Another approach is to setup autolayout constraints, and change height anchor of the bottom view by setting `NSLayoutConstraint`'s constant to 0.

Anyway, whichever of the appraoch will you choose, you will have to tell the tableView to refresh its display (from the viewcontroller):

```
func refreshTableAfterCellExpansion() {
    self.tableView.beginUpdates()
    self.tableView.setNeedsDisplay()
    self.tableView.endUpdates()
}
```

E.g., check following [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46583353/uitableviewcell-custom-class-reload-cell-height-after-change-in-subview-height/46583799#46583799) and its [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46583799/2912282).

An example using playgrounds (the one with the `UIStackView`, the other one uses the same principle):

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

class ExpandableCellViewController: UITableViewController, ExpandableCellDelegate {

    override func loadView() {
        super.loadView()

        tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44
        tableView.register(ExpandableCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "expandableCell")
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 5
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "expandableCell", for: indexPath) as! ExpandableCell
        cell.delegate = self
        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? ExpandableCell {
            cell.isExpanded = true
        }
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? ExpandableCell {
            cell.isExpanded = false
        }
    }

    func expandableCellLayoutChanged(_ expandableCell: ExpandableCell) {
        refreshTableAfterCellExpansion()
    }

    func refreshTableAfterCellExpansion() {
        self.tableView.beginUpdates()
        self.tableView.setNeedsDisplay()
        self.tableView.endUpdates()
    }
}

protocol ExpandableCellDelegate: class {
    func expandableCellLayoutChanged(_ expandableCell: ExpandableCell)
}

class ExpandableCell: UITableViewCell {
    weak var delegate: ExpandableCellDelegate?

    fileprivate let stack = UIStackView()
    fileprivate let topView = UIView()
    fileprivate let bottomView = UIView()

    var isExpanded: Bool = false {
        didSet {
            bottomView.isHidden = !isExpanded
            delegate?.expandableCellLayoutChanged(self)
        }
    }

    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        selectionStyle = .none

        contentView.addSubview(stack)
        stack.addArrangedSubview(topView)
        stack.addArrangedSubview(bottomView)

        stack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        topView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        bottomView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            stack.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor),
            stack.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leftAnchor),
            stack.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.rightAnchor),
            stack.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor),

            topView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50),

            bottomView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30),
            ])

        stack.axis = .vertical
        stack.distribution = .fill
        stack.alignment = .fill
        stack.spacing = 0

        topView.backgroundColor = .red
        bottomView.backgroundColor = .blue
        bottomView.isHidden = true
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}

// Present the view controller in the Live View window
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = ExpandableCellViewController()
```

Comment: Ah okay, I’ve never used UIStackView before, I’ll have to take a look

Comment: @MattSanford I have added a playgrounds example that you can use as a starting point

Comment: I keep running into the height constraint issue on the content view when the elements go from hidden to not.

Comment: This is the solution and it works correctly, I would just like to get rid of the errors in the console

Comment: what errors? unsatisfiable constraints? if that's the case and one of them is `UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height` or `UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width`, go see my answer to this question (that is a known issue with the dynamic height cells): https://stackoverflow.com/a/47937781/2912282

Answer (score 0):

I would simply define 2 cell types, and select the one which is appropriate in tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)

Comment: Are you saying that I would remove the “collapsed” Version and add insert the expanded row? I’ve read there was performance troubles associated with that

Comment: The idea would be to implement it in tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath). Call dequeueReusableCell with the Identifier corresponding to collapsed or expanded, for the given row. I've not looked at performance point of view.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a flag to indicate if specific section or row is expanded and use this methods on UITableView:

```
    reloadRows()
    reloadSections()
```

And Change heightForRow method to return desired height according to the flag.
If you want to be able to expand more than one row at a time you can use a ViewModel for each item in your datasource and update a flag in it when didSelectItemAt or didDeselectItemAt methods called and then reload row or section with the desired animation.

Comment: I tried this, but the issue was that I’m not sure of where to attach subviews so that it displays appropriately

Comment: If you use reloadRows or reloadSections this will call cellForRow method you can adjust views there, you might want to add the views always but with 0 height constraint and then change the views height constraints in cellForRow method.