# Resize cell when click on custom button in Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift

I have a view controller in which i have used table view controller in it. In my cell there is a button on which when user  click the cell size should come to 550 and when click again it should come back to its original height. I have tried bit code after searching for it but it isn't working is their any solution that can work for me?. My code is bit this,

```
var indexOfCellToExpand: Int!

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
  if indexPath.row == indexOfCellToExpand {
    return 170 + expandedLabel.frame.height - 38
  }
  return 170
}
```

Comment: Use two different cell, one for expanded item and one for collapsed item

Comment: show your button action method

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Programmatically creating an expanding UItableViewCell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47963568/programmatically-creating-an-expanding-uitableviewcell)

Comment: i haven't  coded anything in button action yet. @PrashantTukadiya

Comment: What is going to be in the extra space?  If you are using dynamically sized cells you could place a UIStackView in the cell and then show/hide the extra view.

Comment: Use autolayout To collapse and expand cell. which will manage automatic

Comment: how can i get the height of cell on a custom button clicked? @BhargavB.Bajani

Comment: Check Attached Demos in below Ans. @Hamza Imran

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Auto layout for Expand-collapse Cell,
Attaching Demo for that case

link:https:[//www.dropbox.com/s/ieltq0honml35l8/TAbleDemo.zip?dl=0.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ieltq0honml35l8/TAbleDemo.zip?dl=0)

set cell button height constraint and update constraint on Value on select- deselect event and just reload data

in main viewcontroller code

```
self.tblView.estimatedRowHeight = 100
self.tblView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 3
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TblCell", for: indexPath) as! TblCell

        cell.btnExpandCollepse.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.expandCollapse(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        return cell

    }

 @objc func expandCollapse(sender:UIButton) {

        self.tblView.reloadData()
    }
```

Code in Cell Class

```
@IBOutlet var btnExpandCollepse: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var constraintBtnHeight: NSLayoutConstraint!

@IBAction func onExpandCollepse(_ sender: UIButton) {

        sender.isSelected = !sender.isSelected

        if !sender.isSelected{

            self.constraintBtnHeight.constant = 50
        }else{
            self.constraintBtnHeight.constant = 500
        }
    }
```

for constraint check below image 
http://prntscr.com/hur8ym

**Updated Demo for custom Content height of Lable with Autoresizing Cell**
https://www.dropbox.com/s/o742kflg5yeofb8/TAbleDemo%202.zip?dl=0

https://www.dropbox.com/s/o742kflg5yeofb8/TAbleDemo%202.zip?dl=0

Comment: why u reload entire tableview? Instead, reload row that you want to expand or shrink

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 4.x**

```
fileprivate var expandedIndexSet = Set<IndexPath>()

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if expandedIndexSet.contains(indexPath) {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CELL_EXPANDED", for: indexPath) as! CellExpanded
        return cell
    } else {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CELL_COLLAPSED", for: indexPath) as! CellCollapsed
        return cell
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: false)
    if expandedIndexSet.contains(indexPath) {
        expandedIndexSet.remove(indexPath)
    } else {
        expandedIndexSet.insert(indexPath)
    }
    tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
}
```

Comment: have to place two cells with eachother? @SPatel

Comment: While you could to this you don't really need to.  You can just use dynamically sized cells and then adjust the size of the content of the cell and it will change it's height.  This allows for better animations.  Depending on what you want in the cell a `UIStackView` is probably the way to go.

Comment: @HamzaImran Just conditionally return cell type in 
tableView(:UITableView, cellForRowAt: ) method and reload cell on click event simple

Comment: And also use self size tableview if possible