# Expande/collapse a tableView cell with a button and show other elements in the view when the cell expands

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift4

I just added a button on my custom cell

[image]

the button "Look at the reviews", what i would like to do is expand or collapse the cell by tapping this button, i also would like to show other labels when the cell expands. For now to know which cell i'm going to tap i created a tag in my cellForRowAt

```
cell.reviewButton.tag = indexPath.row
cell.reviewButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(CourseClass2.ReviewButtonTap(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
```

and the IBAction

```
@IBAction func ReviewButtonTap(_ sender: UIButton) {

      let index2 = IndexPath(row: sender.tag, section: 0)


}
```

but i don't know how can i expand or collapse and especially i do not know how to show other elements in the cell when it expands, i already looked around the net but i didn't find useful tutorial, i'm a beginner can someone explain me how to do?

Comment: take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47963568/2912282

My answer there explains it in enough details.

Comment: Agreed take a look at @MilanNosáľ answer.  You may also want to look into using [Dynamic TableView Cell Heights](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18746929/using-auto-layout-in-uitableview-for-dynamic-cell-layouts-variable-row-heights) , to use along with the stackViews.

Comment: My answer there uses dynamic height already, but yeah, it's good to take a look specifically to that, too.

Comment: StackViews are the way to go, if you wanna get a better understanding about them, take a look at this tutorial https://www.raywenderlich.com/160646/uistackview-tutorial-introducing-stack-views-2

Comment: And if you'll find my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/47963680/2912282 useful, I would appreciate if you leave an upvote :)

Comment: yes now i'm studying you answer to better understand, a question, you add constraints to the cell also with the storyboard or only the code i see in your answer?

Comment: and also how can i add this import PlaygroundSupport ?

Comment: I concur with @MilanNosáľ his other question using stack views and dynamic height is the way to go.  In honour of this I will award you an upvote.

Comment: Why do u need import PlaygroundSupport. That is only for playground projects.. I'm pretty sure you have an iOS project with .xcodeproj extension @fisherM

Comment: ah ok understand

Comment: @fisherM my example there is a full working solution, you don't need any storyboards for it. if you want to use storyboards, just create `@IBOutlet`s of the constraints and views you need to manage

Comment: understand, thank you

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is the best approach to do it. But I will create `headers` instead of `cells` and when the `button` "Look at the reviews" pressed, I will `add` and `remove` a cell respect to that header.

Check this tutorial: https://newfivefour.com/swift-ios-expanding-uitableview-sections.html.

In `numberOfRowsInSection` you can decide expand/collapse action respect of that header.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if hidden[section] {
        return 0
    } else {
        return 1
    }
}
```

Comment: Using headers and adding/removing cells will only increase the complexity. I don't thin this is the best approach, if you use UIStackViews you can easily set the isHidden flag to true/false and display any extra labels... I don't think this question requires such complexity!