# How to change height Constraint of UIView in UitableviewCell when using UITableViewAutomaticDimension

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios-autolayout, uitableviewautomaticdimension

[image]

I have a UIView in the UITableViewCell , which needs to change its height when user taps on "less/more" button

My code is

```
 - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView       estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}
```

Comment: take a look here, and next time try to research a bit before asking a question (there are many question about expandable cells): https://stackoverflow.com/a/47963680/2912282

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Programmatically creating an expanding UItableViewCell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47963568/programmatically-creating-an-expanding-uitableviewcell)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hook items height constraint as IBOutlet and change it in **cellForRow** like this

```
 cell.viewHeightCon.constant = // value
```

and before return cell add

```
 cell.layoutIfNeeded()
```

Comment: Can you plz tell me how to set the priorities of constraints to fix it?

Comment: no need to fix priorities this will stretch automatically , see design your cell prototype or xib in expanded state and hook height of ones you want to change in runtime as iboutlets

Comment: I did the same as you suggested & set the clipsTobounds property yes, which resolved my issue..