# How to manage the items in the storyboard to add the possibility to expand/collapse the cell of the tableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uistoryboard, swift4

I'm trying to create in my tableView the ability to expand and collapse the various cells with a click, not considering the code, how I have to set the elements and constraints in the storyboard? In the sense, in the content view of my cell how many UIView should I add, assuming that I want to double the size of the cell when I expand it, this UIView I have to add one on top of the same size? The constraints instead? I already tried to give a look at some tutorials but they were not too clear about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `UIStackView` to contain your content of the cell, and design the cell as expanded. Then just set `view.isHidden = true` for those `stackView`'s arranged subviews that should be collapsed. Then you can switch between expanding and collapsing the cell by setting `isHidden` to true or false on appropriate subviews (that you will do in an `@IBAction` as a reaction to clicking a button, or something similar). But there will still be some other parts that you will have to take care in the code to make it work, see my answer in [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46583799/2912282). A programmatical example of what you want you will find in this [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47963568/programmatically-creating-an-expanding-uitableviewcell), if you know to read the code you'll know how to do it in storyboards  - the principle is the same, you just need to setup constraints and contents in storyboards.